# Spring Boot: exception while exiting application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to run a Spring application that should exit after it has done its work. But in my implementation I get an exception.

`build.gradle` contains:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
}
```

`Application.java`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void doTheWorkAndExit() {
        // do the work ...
        SpringApplication.exit(context, () -> 0);
    }

}
```

I get the exception

```
Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigAppl
icationContext@1807f5a7: startup date [Fri Mar 11 10:03:27 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:415)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:975)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.close(SpringApplication.java:1252)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.java:1238)
    at mypackage.Application.doTheWorkAndExit(Application.java:34)
    ...
```

What can I do? Is there a better solution than using `System.exit(0)`?

Comment: I think you can't `exit` from application on `@PostConstruct` stage because in this stage Spring Context is not initialized. So try run your work using `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` and in this case app must exit fine because Context is refreshed (initialized).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `Application.class` you can implement `CommandLineRunner` interface.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner{}
```

After implementation you need to implement a void method `run()`

```
@Override
public void run(String... strings) {
    //here starts your code (like in a normal main method in a java application)
}
```

The application shuts down after excecuting all of the code.

---

The complete `Application.class`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner{

  @Override
  public void run(String... strings) {
      //here your code...
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);    
  }
}
```