# run once via Quartz scheduler

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I want to use Quartz to schedule a long running job only once and then the application should shutdown. Is it possible? If yes, then how can I achieve it?

Currently, I am using the following configuration in pom.xml which makes it run every 10s. I came across an attribute called repeatCount but it didn't work for me.

```
 quartz:
  scheduler-properties:
    org:
      quartz:
        jobStore:
          driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
          tablePrefix: quartz.QRTZ_
          isClustered: true
          clusterCheckinInterval: 2000
        scheduler:
          jmx.export: true
          instanceId: ${random.value}
        threadPool:
          threadCount: 2

jobs:
  enabled: true
  schedules:
    - jobClass: com.me.mypackage.jobs.OneTimeJob
      enabled: true
      intervalInMs: 10000
```

Comment: so you just want to start the application -> run the job once -> and shut down the application?

Comment: yes I want to do the same.

Comment: not sure if you really need a job for that. But if its not necessary you can implement commanLineRunner like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35936627/3493036) and run your logic. You can start the app via cronjob.